# passing variable as JQuery CSS selector not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, variables, jquery-selectors

Here is my first part of the code:

```
$('ul li').click(function(){ //when an <li> is clicked

    $('ul .clicked').removeClass('clicked'); // remove .clicked class from any other <li>'s inside a <ul>
    $(this).addClass('clicked'); // add .clicked class to the clicked <li> ($(this))

    screen = $(this).attr('id'); // screen = the clicked elements' id
    screen = "#" + screen; // screen = the clicked elements' id with a # infront of it 
    $(screen).screenSlide(); // is basically = $('#elementsID').screenSlide();, correct?
});
```

It's weird because in a previous function which I wrote, I did the exact same thing except the last step, instead of passing screen as a selector, I pushed screen inside an Array and then I grabbed array[0] (which was #elementsID without any quotations) and used that as a selector and it worked. But moving forward, screenSlide is

```
function screenSlide(){ // $(this) should = an <li> who's id is screen
    var test = $(this).attr('class');
    alert(test);
    $(this).addClass('current'); // add the .current class to $(this), which should be an <li>
    $(this).slideDown();
};
```

now, alert test didn't alert anything, so I'm guessing that passing screen as a CSS selector didn't work. As you can see, the screenSlide function is supposed to add a class to the $(this) < li > and then make it slide up.

Any idea on what's wrong?

Comment: Do you mean that the alert box shows up with `undefined`, or does it not show up at all?  Also, are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Why don't you just call `screenSlide(this);`?

Comment: @SuperScript , when I do that, the alert box says undefined.

Comment: Are you duplicating ids?

Comment: @PSL , perfect, worked! And no I wasn't duplicating ID's, you are right, I could've just down screenSlide(this);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have defined it, `screenSlide` is just a function, not attached to jquery object. Inorder to be invoked as a function on jquery object you need to add it as `$.fn.screenSlide`.

```
$.fn.screenSlide = function(){
    var test =this.attr('class');
    alert(test);
    this.addClass('current'); // add the .current class to $(this), which should be an <li>
    this.slideDown();
    return this; //return this to enable chaining
}
```

Inside this function you dont need to redefind the jquery object as $(this) since this will already be a jquery object, and also return `this` to enable it for chaining.

If you want to invoke it separately then you can use [function.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

```
screenSlide.call($(this));
```

With this `this` is again jquery object you dont need to do `$(this)` inside your function all over again.

*By the way it seems like you just need to invoke it as `$(this).screenSlide();` unless you are duplicating the ids, in which case it won't behave the way you expect anyways.*

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3gqma/)**

Answer (score 1):

`$(screen).screenSlide();` will throw an error saying there is no such method as `screenSlide` for object because `screenSlide` is not a method associated with the jQuery wrapper object. You need to write `screenSlide` as a plugin for that

```
$.fn.screenSlide = function(){
    var test = this.attr('class');
    alert(test);
    this.addClass('current'); // add the .current class to $(this), which should be an <li>
    this.slideDown();
}
```

or invoke `screenSlide` with a custom context like

```
screenSlide.call($(screen))
```

Comment: Hm interesting. So how do I make screenSlide a method associated with the JQuery wrapper object?

Comment: @user2817200 if you write it as a plugin as given above it will be associated with the jQuery wrapper object